# On linux, what are /dev/tmp-scsi-* device nodes?

Tags: linux

On a CentOS 5.5 server, I have over 10000 of these in `/dev/` with names like `/dev/tmp-scsi-maj253-min4-21054/`.

This is a development machine that has various LVM, mdraid, multipath, iSCSI devices on, so I don't know where these nodes came from.  What drivers or services would create `/dev/tmp-scsi-*` device nodes?